# Измерить расстояние до ближайшего такси

Tags: python, python-3.x

Мне нужно написать код в котором я смогу найти ближайшее такси до заданного адреса. Я делал похожую задачу, но там нужно было определить расстояния между деревнями. Там я создавал список списков и делал новую таблицу, где всё расписано. Но сейчас у меня почему-то не получается.

```
avenues_df = pd.DataFrame([0, 153, 307, 524], index=['Park', 'Lexington', '3rd', '2nd'])
streets_df = pd.DataFrame([0, 81, 159, 240, 324], index=['76', '75', '74', '73', '72'])

address = ['Lexington', '74']
taxies = [
    ['Park', '72'],
    ['2nd', '75'],
    ['3rd', '76'],
]

address_vector = np.array([avenues_df.loc[address[0]], streets_df.loc[address[1]]])
taxi_distances = []


index = 
print(taxies[index])
```

taxies - места стоянки машин

address - адрес по которому они должны приехать

avenues_df, streets_df - координаты улиц и авеню.

А вот подобная задача про деревни, мне кажется, что с такси должна решаться подобным способом, но я не могу догнать как.

```
distances = []
for village_from in range(len(village)):
    row = []
    for village_to in range(len(village)):
        value = distance.euclidean(vectors[village_from], vectors[village_to])
        row.append(value)
    distances.append(row)

distances_df = pd.DataFrame(distances, index=village, columns=village)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задача учебная? Тогда должно быть сказано использовать-ли эвклидово расстояние или манхеттенское расстояние.  Во втором случае надо использовать метод cityblock из пакета scipy.spatial.distance.

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cityblock
dist=[]
address_vector = np.array([avenues_df.loc[address[0]], streets_df.loc[address[1]]])
for car in taxies:
    taxies_vector=np.array([avenues_df.loc[car[0]], streets_df.loc[car[1]]])
    dist.append(cityblock(address_vector,taxies_vector))
ind=dist.index(min(dist))
print ('Ближайшее такси расположено по адресу авенью ', taxies[ind][0], ',улица ',taxies[ind][1])
print ('Расстояние доезда - ',min(dist))
```

Результат:

```
Ближайшее такси расположено по адресу авенью  3rd ,улица  76
Расстояние доезда -  313
```

Comment: Да учебная, спасибо. Всегда грустно задавать вопросы, потому что, когда читаешь ответ думаешь "А как я до этого не дошел" и становится грустно